# unfinlished texture bake

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking

Im trying to bake in cycles but result is unfinished, little new to blender and modeling ,
Here is screenshot:

[image]

And blend file : [image]

(note the download link is not working, probably due to a hashtag character, but this works: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/d/4129/2House.blend)

Note : used smart UV project.

Comment: please, use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload (small) files, then edit your question and paste the provided link. It's a dedicated and permanent storage that will preserve your file for this site, to benefit future readers...

Comment: you have 2 images set for baking: XOXO and XOSS: check XOXO, soes it have the details missing in XOSS (image shown)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in the file that you unwrapped only parts of the mesh, those which have ssignede 2 materials (1 baking to XOXO, the other to XOSS), but other materials have no texture assigned, so they don't bake, anywhere:

[image]

[image]